# html flex: border around item without expand in height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the following example, the border is not around the blue box, but expands over all window height.

Any hint to make a border around the blue box ?

Notes:

- html and body definitions can not be changed.
- padding in "div1" can not be changed.
- I've tried different combinations with , "display:inline-block" etc, without success.
- It is very probable this question has been already asked. However, my search of the answer has been unsuccessful. A good "duplicate" hint is welcome.

```css
html {
 height: 100%;
}

body {
 height: 100%;
  margin: 0; 
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
}

#div1 {
 padding: 2em; 
 border: 1px solid green;
}

#blueDiv {
 width: 5em;
 height: 5em;
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="div1">
    <div id="blueDiv"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don’t you use *outline* and *outline-offset* directly on *#blueDiv*?

```css
html {
 height: 100%;
}

body {
 height: 100%;
  margin: 0; 
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
}

#div1 {
 padding: 2em;
}

#blueDiv {
 width: 5em;
 height: 5em;
 background-color: blue;
 /* OUTLINE */
 outline: 1px solid green; 
 outline-offset: 5px; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="div1">
    <div id="blueDiv"></div>
  </div>
    <p>There is a green border around the blue box, distant 5 pixels.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Why don’t you use outline and outline-offset directly on #blueDiv?" Because I didn't know they exists. Thanks a lot for the suggestion.